# Wrong equation number displayed in section title only and not elsewhere

Tags: numbering

I am encountering a strange bug.

```
\begin{align}
\c_1 & = ..., \label{adgm::eq:v2-c1}\\
\c_D & = ..., \label{adgm::eq:v2-cD} \\
\c_d & = ... \notag\\
     & ...\label{adgm::eq:v2-cd}
\end{align}
```

And later in an appendix file I reference to the above equations:

```
\section{Proof of~\eqref{adgm::eq:v2-c1},~\eqref{adgm::eq:v2-cD} and~\eqref{adgm::eq:v2-cd}}\label{append::adgm:proof-adgm2}
Proof of~\eqref{adgm::eq:v2-c1},~\eqref{adgm::eq:v2-cD} and~\eqref{adgm::eq:v2-cd}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

As we observe, (5.27) was displayed as (5.28) in the section title. What's even stranger is that the title is correct in the **table of contents**:

[image]

Could you please help me to fix this? I am using XeLaTeX in TeX Live 2018 under macOS.

Thank you very much in advance!

**Update:** Below is a minimal working example:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\newfontfamily\myheaderfont[Numbers=OldStyle,Scale=MatchLowercase]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setsecheadstyle{\myheaderfont\Large\mdseries\scshape\lowercase}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
\begin{align}
c_1 &= \dots, \label{adgm::eq:v2-c1}\\
c_D &= \dots, \label{adgm::eq:v2-cD} \\
c_d &= \dots \notag\\
        & \dots\label{adgm::eq:v2-cd}
\end{align}

\section{Proof of~\eqref{adgm::eq:v2-c1},~\eqref{adgm::eq:v2-cD} and~\eqref{adgm::eq:v2-cd}}\label{append::adgm:proof-adgm2}
Proof of~\eqref{adgm::eq:v2-c1},~\eqref{adgm::eq:v2-cD} and~\eqref{adgm::eq:v2-cd}
\end{document}
```

I also removed the tag `hyperref` as it turns out to be irrelevant.

**Update 2:**

It turns out that `\lowercase` is the cause. I would like to keep it though, because of aesthetic reason. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: you didn't provide usable code but your image hints at the reason, you are uppercasing the section heading and your labels just differ by case, (but actually I would have expected them all to be uppercased and not work. Please fix your example so people can run it and debug the issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I'm trying to reproduce this with a minimal working example and will post it as soon as possible.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please see the update of the question. Another problem is that the scale of the equation numbers is too hight compared to the section title, but maybe I should post this as a separate question. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed, your guess about casing is right. I tried removing `\lowercase` in the definition of `\setsecheadstyle` and the problem no longer occurred. I would like to keep it though, because of aesthetic reason.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I guess the labels do work because they are actually being converted to *lowercase* and printed in small caps.

Comment: by far the easiest is to replace D by d2 in the label since you know you are going to use it in a lowercase context

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, it's a shame that I couldn't think about that :( I would say this is the best solution! Please post your answer so that I can accept it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest is to replace D by d2 in the label since you know you are going to use it in a lowercase context.